# Retrieve ArrayList Json object from AJAX

Tags: java, jquery, json, ajax

I have the following code that retrieves data from a database:

```
List<LocationBean> Locations = new ArrayList<LocationBean>();

        /*
         * The following logic iterates through the database entries
         * */

        for(int i = 1; i<=10; ++i){

            String query ="SELECT * FROM Energyinfo.Info WHERE id_number = " +i;
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);


            while(rs.next()){
                int id = rs.getInt("id_number");
                int kw = rs.getInt("kilowatts_used");
                double lat = rs.getDouble("Latitude");
                double lon = rs.getDouble("Longitude");
                LocationBean temp = new LocationBean(id, kw, lat, lon);
                Locations.add(temp);


        }}
        String jsonData = new Gson().toJson(Locations);
        System.out.println(jsonData);
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        response.getWriter().write(jsonData);
```

I am not sure if this is properly set up to be retrieved in the front end. However, I would like to use AJAX in a JSP to retrieve this JSON object to display out on the screen. I want this to be dynamic, as the data in the database database can be subject to change.

Comment: I should mention this code is in a doGet method within a servlet

Comment: if you want to just send `json` why not jsut create a `json` ?

Comment: Can you show an example in this situation?

Comment: PS how would I retrieve each json object in the front end?

Comment: To answer your last question: you parse them with a JavaScript function.